# Retaining MM/DD/YYYY format in String

Tags: c#

I need to write date in MM/DD/YYYY format. From a Date Picker Control. I try to assign it to a DateTime variable. Before Writing it to a file I assign it to a string. I see the value stored in String variable is in DD/MM/YYYY format.

Below is assignment statement

```
DateTime startTime, endTime;
string startTimeDate = "";
startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dpStartTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dpEndTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
startTimeDate = startTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
startTimeDate = startTimeDate.Replace('-', '/');
```

I observe startTimeDate is stored as DD/MM/YYYY only. startTime is storing as MM/DD/YYYY format only. Please let me know if there is any other approach to correctly assign / convert the date values.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

You are losing the original date in your `Convert.DateTime()` conversion, you have to apply the format string here as well e.g. using `DateTime.ParseExact` :

```
startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dpStartTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"),
                                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: As I said startTimeDate is returning as DD/MM/YYYY which is a issue for me. Please suggest.

Comment: I get Error - The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context. I removed mscorlib from references stil I got another error.

Comment: What is the error? - this works for me, `CultureInfo` is in the `System.Globalization` namespace

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Convert.ToDateTime()`, try to use `DateTime.ParseExact(string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider)` when you can ensure the datetime format and want to ignore the system settings. MSDN Reference for the DateTime.ParseExact() method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're converting `DateTime` to string, then you're converting it again to `DateTime` using `Convert` class. You're not preserving the format here cause `DateTime` is format agnostic. And default `ToString` conversion (used by debugger) is in your cause MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: Can you suggest me alternate work around. I am trying to figure out what is the code fix for this case.

Comment: `startTimeDate = startTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")`
there is nothing wrong about it

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [String.Format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/), ex

```
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dpStartTime.Value);
```

To format dates as strings.